# How to exit a loop in lisp once the function is performed?

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

I am very beginner in LISP and hope that you can solve my confusion for me. My code is as follow:

```lisp
(defun retrieve (element closed)
  (if (= (length closed) 0)
      (setf closedlist '(a))
      (dolist (count closed)
        (when (equal element (car count))
          (progn (check (childvalue (symbol-value count)) count) 
                 (return)));;;endif
        );;;endouterloop
      )
  )
```

This is the first function, where it will take in an object called "element", and a list called "closed". The next function is as below:

```lisp
(defun check (child close)
  (setf tempvalue child)
  (dotimes (count (length tempvalue));;;1st loop
    (setf front (car tempvalue))
    (setf templist close)
    (dotimes (count1 (length close));;;2nd loop
      (if (= (length close) 1) 
          (if (string= front (car templist)) 
              ((remove (nth count) child) (return));;;true
              (setf templist (car templist));;;else
              )
          (if (string= front (car templist)) 
              (setf child (remove (nth count child) child))
              (setf templist (cdr templist));;;else
              )
          )
      );;;2nd loop
    (setf tempvalue (cdr tempvalue))
    );;;1stloop
  (format t "child ~S~%" child)
  )
```

My question is, from the 1st function, when I am inside the first function and if the condition is met, I will call the second function (check). However, after I call the 2nd function (check) from the 1st function (retrieve) and successfully performed the operations, I want to exit the dotimes loop from the 1st function but I can't do it.

If I try to add (return) to it, the program will just exit the loop, without performing other things inside the statement. In this case, (check (childvalue (symbol-value temp)) (nth count closed)).

Could anybody provide any suggestion on how to exit the loop after calling the secondary function? Thanks.

Comment: This is very poor code: unformatted code, lots of undeclared variables, access to list elements via NTH in loops, several errors in the function CHECK, repeated computation of the length of a list... You should throw the code away and start fresh. Use a Lisp compiler - it will give you lots of errors and warnings.

Comment: @RainerJoswig sorry, I am very beginner at this.. Would you mind giving me an example on the "undeclared variables" ? And is there any better way to access to list elements other than via NTH in loops?

Comment: @Piiinkyy don't worry now, you'll learn. You're kinda typing C-style in lisp's syntax now though..

Comment: @RainerJoswig Piiinkyy is obviously new on stackoverflow and new in lisp, and for double-beginner, he posted pretty damn clear, well formated and perfectly valid question. You have to give him some credit about that!

Comment: Here is a free download of a book which explains basic Lisp in a good way: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: @enrey will think about it, thank you.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I will try to look through the book, thanks.

Comment: The variable `temp` in `retrieve` is undeclared. `tempvalue`, `front`, `templist` in `check` are also undeclared. A Lisp compiler will tell you that.

Comment: @Piiinkyy did you check my answer down there btw?

Comment: @enrey yeap I did. But I am still figuring out on what is the problem for the "Nth" part.

Comment: @Piiinkyy little hint: `dolist`

Comment: @enrey thinking bout it now. Btw, do I still have to use Nth with dolist? Or is it best not to use nth at all?

Comment: @enrey it's okay, I figured it out already. Thank you so much!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `nth`, but bear in mind that to access n-th element of list, the computer has to go through n-1 elements before that to get there, it's gonna be slow on big data and it's not the "lispy" way. You already have that `nth` in two nested loops, plus remove always rebuilds the list from scratch, it has to go through the whole list too. Thus algorithmic complexity of this is at least O(n^3). And the code as it is now doesn't really work, edit that question and add more info about what are you trying to achieve, maybe we can rewrite it into something faster and cleaner.

Comment: @enrey i see. Does the codes look better now? 

   (defun retrieve (element closed)
               (dolist (count closed)
                 (when (equal element (car count))
   (progn (check (childvalue (symbol-value temp)) count) 
    (return)));;;endif
                 );;;endouterloop
               )

However, this function takes in two variables (element and closed), where element is the name of an object, while closed is a nested list. The main purpose here is to make a comparison between the "object name" and the names inside the lists of the nested lists (thus, CAR).

Comment: @enrey I'm sorry, I didnt know the codes will turn out like this when post in the comment.

Comment: @Piiinkyy I don't think you need to use symbol-value, plus 'temp is undefined there. You might as well rename `count` to something better. But anyway, this looks better.

Comment: @Piiinkyy btw, you can click edit on your question and change it.

Comment: @enrey Alright, will do. One more thing, as from the code, (when (equal element (car count)), let's say my count only has one value in it, which is (A), why this error "Error: Attempt to take the car of A which is not listp." came out when I'm trying to run it? Any suggestion?

Comment: You should take a look at this short [guide for formatting Lisp code.](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html)

Comment: @danlei I get a certificate error from that URL.

Comment: @Barmar Here you go: https://web.archive.org/web/20221003191033/https://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html

Answer (score 0):

`if` has a format `(if <condition> <if-true> <if-false>)`.

You wrote `(if <condition> (check ...) (break) )`, so the `break` was in the `<if-false>` position and went off first time the condition was false. To group multiple statements into one, use `progn`.

```
(if (equal element temp)
    (progn (check (childvalue (symbol-value temp)) (nth count closed)) 
           (return)))
```

Progn doesn't do anything except groups statements together and returns the result of the last one.

You can as well use `when` instead of `if`. `When` works like `(when <condition> <if-true>... )`. It can have multiple if-trues but no if-false. I think that's perfect for your situation.

Just for completeness, the opposite of `when` is `unless`. It has multiple if-falses and no if-true. `(unless cond ...)` is equivalent to `(when (not cond) ...)`

SIDE-NOTE: As a side note, put closing parentheses on same line, don't put `)` on separate lines. Your editor should indent stuff for you, then just look and navigate yourself by indentation and forget those closing parens. Once you start doing that, the code will seem more clear than many traditional languages.

SECOND-SIDE-NOTE: 
if you want local variables, use `let`, or you'd get undeclared variable notices in certain implementation. Example:

```
(defun check (child close)
  (let ((tempvalue child)
        (front)
        (templist))
    (dotimes (count (length tempvalue))
      (setf front (car tempvalue))
      (setf templist close)
      (dotimes (count1 (length close))
        (if (= (length close) 1) 
            (if (string= front (car templist)) 
                ((remove (nth count) child) (return))
                (setf templist (car templist)))
            (if (string= front (car templist)) 
                (setf child (remove (nth count child) child))
                (setf templist (cdr templist)))))
      (setf tempvalue (cdr tempvalue)))
    (format t "child ~S~%" child)))
```

Comment: @RainerJoswig ah I see your point now, I missed this. I'll rewrite it.

Comment: ok, I won't rewrite it, I can't figure out what is it supposed to do